# Nesting python in R

Tags: python, r, bash, syntax, nested

I would like to apply a python code using R. However, due to the R syntax to escape quotes I got an error. This code works directly in bash.

```
df <- 'anm1 sam1 TT GG AA BB'
df <- read.table(text=df, header=F)
write.table(df, "df.txt", col.names=F, row.names=F, quote=F)
```

In bash:

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(' '.join(c) for c in zip(*(l.split() for l in sys.stdin.readlines() if l.strip()))))" < df.txt > dfout.txt

cat dfout.txt

anm1
sam1
TT
GG
AA
BB
```

When trying to nest it in R:

```
system("python -c \"import sys; print('\n'.join(' '.join(c) for c in zip(*(l.split() for l in sys.stdin.readlines() if l.strip()))))\" < df.txt > dfout.txt")

>     File "<string>", line 1
>         import sys; print('
>                           ^
>     SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Some idea to make the syntax work here?

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful? Please mark accepted if it solved your problem, or let me know if it's incorrect in some way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be escaping your text with [shQuote](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/shQuote.html) before attempting to run it, especially if there's a chance there will be variable data in it. But, at a minimum you need to escape the backslashes in the text:

```
system("python -c \"import sys; print('\\n'.join(' '.join(c) for c in zip(*(l.split() for l in sys.stdin.readlines() if l.strip()))))\" < df.txt > dfout.txt")
```

If you use [system2](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html), shQuote is done automatically, and you can use the built-in facilities for input redirection,

```
cmd <- "python"
args <- c(
    "-c",
    "\"import sys; print('\\n'.join(' '.join(c) for c in zip(*(l.split() for l in sys.stdin.readlines() if l.strip()))))\""
)
system2(cmd, args, stdout="dfout.txt", stdin="df.txt")
```